# Spring Data: Mongo Repository can not be initialized

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm getting this strange error message when I start my spring boot service:

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property storeMpi found for type Patient!

Service can't be started since this exception is raised.

My code is very straight:

```java
public interface PatientRepository
    extends MongoRepository<Patient, String>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Patient>,
        MPIPatientRepository
{
    
}
```

---

```java
public interface MPIPatientRepository {

    Patient storeMpi(Patient patient);

}
```

You can see, that `storeMpi` is a method, not an expected field of my `Patient` entity.

Implementation is straight as well:

```java
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MPIPatientRepository implements cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.repository.MPIPatientRepository {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Patient storeMpi(Patient patient) {
        return this.mongoTemplate.save(patient);
    }
```

I don't quite figure out what's wrong.

Formatted root `CausedBy` is:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ca.uhn.fhir.spring.boot.autoconfigure.FhirAutoConfiguration$FhirRestfulServerConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [ca.uhn.fhir.spring.boot.autoconfigure.FhirAutoConfiguration$FhirRestfulServerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5fe4b535]: Constructor threw exception;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'patientResourceProvider' defined in file [/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-fhir-mongodb/target/classes/cat/gencat/catsalut/hes/mpi/providers/PatientResourceProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'patientService' defined in file [/home/jeusdi/projects/salut/mpi/hes-mpi-fhir-mongodb/target/classes/cat/gencat/catsalut/hes/mpi/service/PatientService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'patientRepository' defined in cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.repository.PatientRepository defined in @EnableMongoRepositories declared on MongoRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableMongoRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: Could not create query for public abstract cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.model.Patient cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.repository.MPIPatientRepository.storeMpi(cat.gencat.catsalut.hes.mpi.model.Patient)! Reason: No property storeMpi found for type Patient!;
nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property storeMpi found for type Patient!
```

Any ideas?

Comment: maybe you should implement the interface PatientRepository in the MPIPatientRepository, not the MPIPatientRepository.

Comment: did you annotate MPIPatientRepository/PatientRepository with `@Repository` or `@Component` and have a constructor at required places, because the error says "Bean instantiation via constructor failed"